# Что делает ">" в css

Tags: css

Подскажите пожалуйста, что означает стрелочка вправо ">" в css?

```
.list-item__inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: .5em;
}

.list-item__items {
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  display: none;
}

.list-item__arrow {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list-item__folder {
  width: 2em;
}

.list-item_open > .list-item__items {
  display: block;
}

.list-item_open > .list-item__inner .list-item__arrow {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Comment: @Fa4stik Пожалуйста, задавайте вопросы на SO только тогда, когда вы достаточно потрудились, чтобы найти ответ в интернете, например в Google

Comment: @LIMPIX64 понял, извините

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Комбинатор '>'

Выбирает только те элементы, которые являются дочерними непосредственно по отношению к указанному элементу. Синтаксис: `A > B`

### Пример

Cелектор `ul > li` выберет только дочерние элементы `<li>`, которые находятся внутри, на первом уровне вложенности по отношению к элементу `<ul>`

#### [Читайте подробнее](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)

Comment: Проще говоря, комбинатор `>`, выбирает только тех детей, которые находятся на первом уровне вложенности родительского элемента.